# On a link href named read more, how do I add read more function properly with css and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, target

The relevant HTML:

```html
   <div id="main">
                
                <h2>Welcome!</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam commodo posuere massa ut pharetra. Donec a quam ac elit eleifend fringilla sit amet in enim. Maecenas at nibh id ante cursus sodales. Duis eget feugiat velit. Sed nec posuere risus, at vulputate lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin eget accumsan felis, rutrum sagittis massa. maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria</p>
                <p class="event"><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
        
        </div>
```

The CSS:

```css
 #main {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
 }
 p {
  text-align: left;
  column-count: 2;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
 } 
 main.open{
  max-height: 1000px;
```

the JS:

```js
var content = document.getElementById("main");
var event1 = document.getElementById("event");

event1.onclick = function(){

if(content.className == "open"){
    content.className == "";
    event1.innerHTML == "Read More";
} else {
    content.className == "open";
    event1.innerHTML == "Show Less";
}

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `id`s at the right places and corrected some mistakes like `==` instead of `=` to change the `innerText`... The use of `classList` instead of `className` which allows to use of some methods like `.contains()`, `.add()` and `.remove()`.

Have a look ;)

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var event1 = document.getElementById("event1");

event1.onclick = function(){

  if(content.classList.contains("open")){
    content.classList.remove("open");
    event1.innerText = "Read more >>";
  } else {
    content.classList.add("open");
    event1.innerText = "Show less <<";
  }
};
```

```css
#main {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
}
p {
  text-align: left;
  column-count: 2;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
.open{
  overflow: unset;
  max-height: unset;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
            
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>
  <p id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Aliquam commodo posuere massa ut pharetra. Donec a quam ac elit eleifend fringilla sit amet in enim. Maecenas at nibh id ante cursus sodales. Duis eget feugiat velit. Sed nec posuere risus, at vulputate lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin eget accumsan felis, rutrum sagittis massa. maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria maria</p>
  <p><a id="event1" href="#">Read more >></a></p>
    
</div>
```

Comment: wow TY that helped, do you know how to get the extra text under the original two columns? when i run the code it keeps making new columns to the right of the original two,,?

Comment: Yes... I edited by removing the `max-height` when opened, using `max-height: unset;`.